# Bash Auto-Completion feature for SSHing into Different Hosts

Tags: bash, ssh, zsh, autocomplete

I have big list of servers which I normally `ssh` to all the time. Is there any way using `bash` or `zsh` so that I can keep the list of hostname and bash auto-completion goes through the file and gives me suggestion for the boxes starting with those letters whenever I type the first few letters of the hostname.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Zsh` completion works with so called ssh bookmarks. These are per host configurations in `~/.ssh/config`.

For example,

```
  host baz
    hostname 192.168.1.2
    port 22
    user warrick

  host bar
    hostname example.com
    port 2200
    user kevin
    identityfile /home/warrick/.ssh/ec2.pem
```

`man ssh_config` to see a full list of options.

**EDIT**

I am using the completion script from [ohmyzsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh):

https://raw.github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/lib/completion.zsh

In similiar style to `ohmyzsh`, I placed the above script into `~/.zsh/libs/completion.zsh` and added this to `~/.zshrc`.

```
# ~/.zshrc
for f in ~/.zsh/libs/*; do
  source $f
done
```

Comment: I don't use zsh but bash...

Comment: Right, the OPs question is for bash or zsh, my comment on your post was simply to favor ~/.ssh/config to /etc/hosts if at all possible, which as per his question is possible when using zsh.

Answer (score 9):

The [bash completion](http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/) package includes completions for `ssh` commands, including:

- `ssh`
- `ssh-add`
- `ssh-copy-id`
- `sshfs`

You can browse the source here: https://alioth.debian.org/scm/browser.php?group_id=100114

Answer (score 6):

Copied from [my own answer on unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136351/autocomplete-server-names-for-ssh-and-scp):

If you are on an Ubuntu host, then you should know that in Ubuntu [the entries in `~/.ssh/known_hosts` are hashed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash/+bug/42382), so SSH completion cannot read them. This is a feature, not a bug. Even by adding `HashKnownHosts no` to `~/.ssh/config` and `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` I was unable to prevent the host hashing.

However, you can read the configured entries from `~/.ssh/config`, which are not hashed. Here is a script for Bash Completion that reads the entries from that file:

```
_ssh() 
{
    local cur prev opts
    COMPREPLY=()
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"
    opts=$(grep '^Host' ~/.ssh/config | awk '{print $2}')

    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "$opts" -- ${cur}) )
    return 0
}
complete -F _ssh ssh
```

Put that script in `/etc/bash_completion.d/ssh` and then source it with the following command:

```
$ . /etc/bash_completion.d/ssh
```

I found [this guide](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/317/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_2) invaluable and I would not have been able to script this without it. Thank you [Steve Kemp](http://www.steve.org.uk/)  for writing that terrific guide!

Comment: +1 but I would replace the awk line with `opts=$(grep '^Host' ~/.ssh/config | sed 's@^Host @@')` because the `~/.ssh/config` syntax allows for multiple names on a single line

Comment: @nhed: Thank you! I did not know that was allowed.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, put any hosts you want to complete in your `/etc/hosts` file.

You need also `bash-completion` package (containing file /etc/bash_completion and directory /etc/bash_completion.d)

and source it in ~/.bashrc (`. /etc/bash_completion` - sometimes it's commented out in /etc/bash.bashrc or in ~/.bashrc).

Comment: I'd recommend against using /etc/hosts. Instead add so called ssh bookmarks in ~/.ssh/config. `man ssh_config` for more details, but it is far more versatile allowing you to specify multiple aliases, username, port, and much much more.

Comment: With archlinux, when I put something in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, I have no completion working for the configured hosts.

Comment: See my extended answer, I am using completion from `ohmyzsh`.

Comment: If you look at [the source](https://alioth.debian.org/scm/browser.php?group_id=100114), you will see that the script checks `known_hosts` as well as the other config files, eg., `~/.ssh/config`