# Autocomplete server names for SSH and SCP

Tags: bash, ssh, autocomplete, scp

I have a few servers configured in [`~/.ssh/config`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config), such as `alpha` and `beta`. How might I configure Bash such that the commands `$ ssh alTab` and `$ scp file.tgz alTab` autocomplete the names of the configured servers?

I don't want to add the servers to *another* file (i.e. a Bash array) each time one is added, as we add and remove servers regularly and the list is quite large.

This is on Kubuntu 12.10, and I do have [bash-completion](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion) installed.

Comment: Do you have the bash-completions package installed for your distro? I think this is part of the standard completion routines although I might be confusing it with zsh.

Comment: My install does exactly this.

Comment: This is on Kubuntu 12.10, and I do have `bash-completion` installed.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

**Found it!!**

It seems that in Ubuntu [the entries in `~/.ssh/known_hosts` are hashed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash/+bug/42382), so SSH completion cannot read them. This is a feature, not a bug. Even by adding `HashKnownHosts no` to `~/.ssh/config` and `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` I was unable to prevent the host hashing.

However, the hosts that I am interested in are also found in `~/.ssh/config`. Here is a script for Bash Completion that reads the entries from that file:

```
_ssh() 
{
    local cur prev opts
    COMPREPLY=()
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"
    opts=$(grep '^Host' ~/.ssh/config ~/.ssh/config.d/* 2>/dev/null | grep -v '[?*]' | cut -d ' ' -f 2-)

    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "$opts" -- ${cur}) )
    return 0
}
complete -F _ssh ssh
```

Put that script in `/etc/bash_completion.d/ssh` and then source it with the following command:

```
$ . /etc/bash_completion.d/ssh
```

I found [this guide](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/317/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_2) ([Archive.org copy](https://web.archive.org/web/20200327211933/https://debian-administration.org/article/317/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_2)) invaluable and I would not have been able to script this without it. Thank you [Steve Kemp](http://www.steve.org.uk/)  for writing that terrific guide!

Comment: It seems that in Centos 6 entries in ~/.ssh/known_hosts over-ride entries in ~/.ssh/config  eg. if you have foo.bar.baz.com in known_hosts then it will match the whole thing if you do "ssh foo"<tab> - this is undesirable if you have a different user or other settings you want applied from the ssh confg. If you have an entry in ssh config that does not autocomplete properly then check if it is present in known_hosts and delete it. It should now work as normal taking the settings from config.

Comment: @Imran-UK: It is known that Ubuntu does not do that sensible thing, under the pretense of security. Apparently the thought is that a malicious entity might, as the user, edit ~/.ssh/config, despite chmod 0600 on the directory. Hey, I wasn't the one who made the decision!

Comment: I use zsh & oh-my-zsh, I just discovered that enabling the "ssh" plugin and putting "HashKnownHosts yes" in my ~/.ssh/config seems to do the right thing. You can change shell whatever the distro so this might be a way around it.

Comment: @Imran-UK: In fact I've tried zsh in the past and I do intend on trying it again. I'll look into that. Shukran my friend!

Comment: I know I'm a little late to the party, but RHEL 7 will autocomplete entries that are in `/etc/hosts`, other distros may do the same.

Comment: Make sure the lines with "Host" do not start with a blank space, otherwise ``grep '^Host' ~/.ssh/config`` will miss them.

Comment: Change your grep to a grep -R ~/.ssh/config.d and it will work for those of us who use the `Include` directive to have multiple config files in something like a `~/.ssh/config.d` directory.

Comment: @Kirk: It seems that [will-Farrell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/241369/will-farrell) has edited the answer to add that directory in manually. If that's not working then you are invited to edit with what _does_ work! Thank you!

Comment: @dotancohen you are correct! I copied the answer from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/181605/149458) which must have the older unedited version.

Comment: Amazing work. Works perfectly on Ubuntu 16.04 and Debian 9. Thanks!

Comment: Note that if you have entries in your .ssh/config with multiple host entires (i.e. shared settings), this will not handle those well.

Comment: I would add sort after cut

Comment: thanks! its just what i needed for my custom sshfs script

Comment: It's also a convenient way to put it in `.bash_profile`
ref: https://gist.github.com/aliang/1024466

Comment: Although this does work for tab-completing hosts, it breaks all other completions with `ssh`, such as `ssh -i ~/.ssh/<tab>`.

Answer (score 24):

#### Pre-packaged

You don't say what distro you're using but on my Fedora 19 system I have the following package installed, `bash-completion` which provides this feature through this completion rule file:

```
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/ssh
```

Here's the package I have installed:

```
$ rpm -aq |grep completion
bash-completion-2.1-2.fc19.noarch
```

If you look through that rule file you'll see stanzas that are interrogating the `$HOME/.ssh/config` file:

```
$ grep config /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/ssh
    local configfile
    local -a config
        # Search COMP_WORDS for '-F configfile' or '-Fconfigfile' argument
                    configfile="$(dequote "${1:2}")"
                    [[ $1 ]] && configfile="$(dequote "$1")"
        _known_hosts_real -a -F "$configfile" "$cur"
    local configfile
        # Search COMP_WORDS for '-F configfile' argument
                    configfile="$(dequote "${1:2}")"
                    [[ $1 ]] && configfile="$(dequote "$1")"
        _known_hosts_real -a -F "$configfile" "$cur"
    local configfile prefix
        # Search COMP_WORDS for '-F configfile' or '-Fconfigfile' argument
                    configfile="$(dequote "${1:2}")"
                    [[ $1 ]] && configfile="$(dequote "$1")"
                _known_hosts_real -c -a -F "$configfile" "$cur"
```

#### Rolling your own

I also found this Gist, [known_hosts_autocomplete.sh](https://gist.github.com/peelman/1773863), that does something similar except with the `$HOME/.ssh/known_hosts` file.

```
# add to ~/.bash_profile, and close/reopen a shell.  Will autocomplete any
# hosts found in known_hosts.

complete -W "$(echo `cat ~/.ssh/known_hosts | cut -f 1 -d ' ' | \
    sed -e s/,.*//g | uniq | grep -v "\["`;)" ssh
```

You could do something similar using your `$HOME/.ssh/config` file if for some reason you're unable to find the completion rule file for `ssh` already pre-packaged.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that Ubuntu does not ship with `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/ssh`. Could you post that entire file somewhere that I might copy it? Thanks!

Comment: You can get all the files from this archive: http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/repo/pkgs/bash-completion/bash-completion-2.1.tar.bz2/4e2a9f11a4042a38ee79ddcd048e8b9e/bash-completion-2.1.tar.bz2

Comment: I'm sorry to be a pain, but even copying the ssh file from that tar archive to `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/ssh` doesn't help! Neither does running the `complete -W ...` command from the Bash prompt. What might be the issue here?

Comment: Thank you. This does seem to be a [known design decision](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash/+bug/42382) in Ubuntu. Thus I am accepting the answer even though I cannot get bash completion working for `ssh` or `scp`.

Comment: Homebrew for OSX also has this: bash-completion and zsh-completions

Comment: On Macos I had to bump to `bash-completion@2` to make this work, e.g. `brew uninstall bash-completion && brew install bash-completion@2`.

Answer (score 13):

I found that the autocomplete was not working because Ubuntu hashes known hosts. You can add

```
Host *
    HashKnownHosts no
```

To your `.ssh/config` file but existing hosts won't be un-hashed.

Comment: Thank you. I've actually already added this directive to `~/.ssh/config` and changed the directive in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`,  and I've removed the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file. After logging into the servers again, the host names are still being saved hashed.

Comment: I have edited my answer; you will need to specify a host and nest the hash directive inside; I didn't list that as many `.ssh/config` files will already have this line. Let me know if that works.

Comment: This is definitely the easy way to do it!  Given that (newer versions of) Ubuntu now have ssh completion enabled, this is probably what is wanted.

Comment: As I added below, you can do this, but you probably shouldn't -- you don't need to in order to get completion working anyway. However, if you don't agree and just wanted to un-hash the existing hosts after adding that above, you can just rm ~/.ssh/known_hosts, and that will cause it to be re-generated (un-hashed) whenever you log into a new server.

Answer (score 11):

To enable ssh autocompletion in Debian and Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install bash-completion
```

Note that this has *nothing at all to do* with known_hosts hashing, contrary to what was stated above and the original question. If you wanted to autocomplete from known_hosts, then of course you would have to disable hashing, but that is *strongly* recommended against.

For example, I have:

```
Host *
    HashKnownHosts yes
```

in my .ssh/config, and I still have ssh auto-completion working just fine against hosts listed in .ssh/config and /etc/hosts. You do need to add the host to .ssh/config as the OP stated:

Host my-awesome-host
    Hostname the.real.host.name

(Or, you can add a host entry to /etc/hosts, which is another source for the Debian/Ubuntu scripts.)

Then, you can just type `ssh my-awe<tab>` and it will be automagically completed. Again, this is even if you HashKnownHosts, which is highly recommended. (Note that bash completion needs to be enabled in your bash shell, and you need to specifically have those scripts installed as above for your distribution.)

Then, add these lines to your `.bashrc` to enable it (requires a logout and log back in, or just a new `bash` typed in to launch a new shell. (You don't need to enable if it's already enabled in `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `/etc/profile` sources `/etc/bash.bashrc`).

```
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

This will enable ssh autocompletion (among other things!) from `~/.ssh/config`, `/etc/hosts`, etc.

Note that Debian defaults to ash instead of bash. You can switch to bash easily:

```
sudo usermod -s /bin/bash "$USER"
```

(You'll need to log out and log back in for this to take effect.)

Answer (score 5):

On Ubuntu 14.04, `ssh` auto-completes servers mentioned in your `~/.ssh/config`

I noticed it when I realized that only one of the servers I commonly access auto-completed.  The only difference between the two was an entry in the ssh config file that was related to authentication.  When I added a new entry to the config file for the other server, it started auto-completing too.

Here's the entry for those who were asking:

```
HOST server-name 
    GSSAPIAuthentication=no
```

I would be very surprised if it mattered what you were specifying in the config (as long as it is still valid, of course).

Comment: Thank you Noah, what was that entry? On my 14.04 and 14.10 systems autocomplete does not work.

Comment: I don't think the entry matters--I am pretty sure it is just having them in there--but I will add the entry to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

On CentOS 7 all it took was
`yum install bash-completion`
to auto complete hosts from `.ssh/config` when typing `ssh` and hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

On macosx `brew install bash-completion` then add the following to ~/.profile

```
if [ -f $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion ]; then
  . $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion
fi
```

Comment: worked for me on macbook pro

Answer (score 1):

Add the following into `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`

```bsh
# Autocomplete ssh commands
WL="$(perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /^Host (.+)$/' ~/.ssh/config | grep -v "*" | tr "\n" " ")"
complete -o plusdirs -f -W "$WL" ssh scp
```

Then run `source ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.bash_profile` to pick up the configuration

Credit > https://blog.tinned-software.net/use-ssh-comfortably-with-command-history-and-auto-complete/

Answer (score 1):

Solution for macOS:

1. Add the following line in `~/.bash_profile`:

   ```
   complete -W "$(echo `cat ~/.ssh/config | grep "^Host " |awk '{print $2}'`;)" ssh
   ```
2. Source your `.bash_profile` or relogin

Neither `brew` nor `bash-complete` is required. `complete` is a Bash internal command.

Comment: For zsh you need also to enable compatibility mode. Place next code in the top of .zshrc file 
```autoload -U +X bashcompinit && bashcompinit
autoload -U +X compinit && compinit
```
Then source it.
Afterward add code from the answer and source .zprofile.
More discussion is here https://github.com/eddiezane/lunchy/issues/57

Comment: Remember that for several releases now MacOS has not been using bash but zsh, so bash completions will be ignored. Bash can be installed from brew, or a zsh equivalent used.

Answer (score 0):

A simple hack that worked for me was to add the hostnames to `~/.ssh/known_hosts` - just one hostname per line, without any host key, i.e.

```
# My list of hostnames for auto-completion
host1.example.com
host2.example.com
```

is enough for auto-completion to work, at least on my machine.

This is useful when, for example, using SSH host certificates, so hosts are not normally added to known_hosts. Of course you have to manage this list yourself somehow.

Answer (score 0):

As a hacky solution for that works on Ubuntu 22.04 and probably other systems, the bash-completion library will look in `~/.ssh/known_hosts2` for hostnames, in addition to other locations. As `~/.ssh/known_hosts` is in active use and full of hashed entries, you can just list your hostnames, one per line, in `~/.ssh/known_hosts2` and they'll be automatically found.

ssh does read the file, but appears content to ignore the incomplete entries, or perhaps is letting the more complete entries in `~/.ssh/known_hosts` override them.