# Autocomplete hostnames when using SSH within history file

Tags: bash, ssh, autocomplete, history

I'm looking for a feature that help me to autocomplete the servers I "sshed" in sometime and are in my `.bash_history` file without messing with `known_hosts` file or `/etc/bash_completition`, just grab them from my `history`.

I cannot mess with the `known_hosts` file because the info in there is like "encrypted" and looking how to avoid this is like not that important.

e.g.

```
$ tail -n 2 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
|1|D90I41jNxFy83ZhAoyG7gj0+LpM=|Zkru+0Yi9Q9UNafHpj1IVMGGnAw= ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEArih5PrEeGsMHm+9ytkiiOgNNIh6fQAEFfdDw9IwkOGs13g+YN6k61rRbdXj97N+vvuGslcCL9uDMY+M6bqDX4k2kGJuvmsSBgIWOjOiOtrW6wWaflGO0OKQ39F1R92Bw3gB1kNg8Es3XjNE1D+CRXt/EQLWLBFmF3p41PpoRg/Gyvw4XqQSMOYdGsr0OaE8ozrXWO2rQo2NDe6BDJzSGqZ234jCtnRLEtFBFvisTEbNCYFRkhKMSfrUecyK5bjHRehEHKfsPxNDTCOl7xrx1DDTng/BIgxyCA21s+xa05oNulkMMd/1qNrekoUUFxwJpb1rf6vrW5CkeMIOhCr5Nxw==
|1|Cl6c716uEoPmovaRDDwkM+bYFTc=|VXUrsTRDptMOg/Nm3anFMwjy5O8= ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEArih5PrEeGsMHm+9ytkiiOgNNIh6fQAEFfdDw9IwkOGs13g+YN6k61rRbdXj97N+vvuGslcCL9uDMY+M6bqDX4k2kGJuvmsSBgIWOjOiOtrW6wWaflGO0OKQ39F1R92Bw3gB1kNg8Es3XjNE1D+CRXt/EQLWLBFmF3p41PpoRg/Gyvw4XqQSMOYdGsr0OaE8ozrXWO2rQo2NDe6BDJzSGqZ234jCtnRLEtFBFvisTEbNCYFRkhKMSfrUecyK5bjHRehEHKfsPxNDTCOl7xrx1DDTng/BIgxyCA21s+xa05oNulkMMd/1qNrekoUUFxwJpb1rf6vrW5CkeMIOhCr5Nxw==
```

I found [this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136351/autocomplete-server-names-for-ssh-and-scp) but for other not important reason, I have not the `~/.ssh/config` file.

Answer (score 2):

Much easier way would be to disable hashing of your `known_hosts` with `HashKnownHosts no` in your `~/.ssh/config` to allow autocomplete from all history, or just list your hosts in your `~/.ssh/config` (you can store there all your `Ports` and `Users`, or create aliases).

I appreciate the creativity, but why to reinvent wheel when we have got already the same functionality out of the box (except Ubuntu shipping `HashKnownHosts yes` by default, which breaks this functionality).

Answer (score 1):

So as I only and only want to know how to autocomplete my hosts targets within the `bash_history` file, I found this feature hoping to help anybody in the same situation.

Just execute the following line

```
$ complete -W "$(echo $(grep '^ssh ' .bash_history | sort -u | sed 's/^ssh //'))" ssh
```

- `complete` - is a bash builtin function. So there is not a binary on the system. It handles how commands will be completed when pressing
- `-W` - make an autocompletition wordlist
- `grep '^ssh' .bash_history` - return all lines that begin with ssh from `.bash_history` file
- `sort -u` - make the output lines uniq
- `sed 's/^ssh //'` - remove the beginning `ssh` string from each line
- `ssh` - when executing `ssh` command

If you not only `ssh hostname` and use others such as `ssh user@hostname` or `ssh user@hostname -p 2222` you must play with the `regex` and `grep|sed` features to only keep the `hostname` or whatever you want to autocomplete

Insert the complete line to your `.bashrc` file so you have the autocomplete feature every you start a session.