# How to make alias interpretive?

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh, alias

I have a list of servers I often connect to, named like `server001`, `server002`... `server999`. I don't want to store 1000 alias hardcoded with these server names. I also don't want to write a function and take the number as the argument.

Is there a way to make alias flexible such that it takes my command input
"`server005`" and transforms it to the commmand "`ssh username@server005.example.com`" without storing a list of hardcoded alias?

Comment: Is it only via ssh that you want this transformation?

Comment: For the time being, I only need this for SSH

Comment: if you're content with `ssh server005`, you can probably do this with your `.ssh/config`.

Comment: You can customize bash's "command not found" handler. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/73262/how-do-i-teach-bash-in-ubuntu-some-curse-words/73282#73282

Comment: Related - [Autocomplete server names for SSH and SCP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/136351/100397)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define the aliases in a loop

```
for l in {0..999}
do
  id=$(printf %03d $l)
  alias server$id="ssh user@server$id"
done
```

That will create the 1000 aliases based on the pattern

```
bash-4.2$ alias | grep server | head
alias server000='ssh user@server000'
alias server001='ssh user@server001'
alias server002='ssh user@server002'
alias server003='ssh user@server003'
alias server004='ssh user@server004'
alias server005='ssh user@server005'
alias server006='ssh user@server006'
alias server007='ssh user@server007'
alias server008='ssh user@server008'
alias server009='ssh user@server009'
```